# SuperDevMode not working with nested script

Tags: javascript, java, google-chrome, gwt, gwt2

I'm trying to get SuperDevMode to work on GWT-2.6.1 with multiple modules.

I've came across an issue whereby the SuperDevMode plugin doesn't appear to pick up Modules that exist at different levels in the DOM. For example in the generated .nocache.js file has the following line :

```
var o=window;
```

This window includes a :

```
__gwt_activeModules
```

variable that contains the modules that exist within that page, so when the bookmarklet is activated it finds the relevant module and replaces it with the .nocache.js file running on the codeserver (I believe !)

However the problem occurs when I try and recompile a module that exists in a different level in the DOM - because the nocache.js window reference is different - the SuperDevMode plugin can only see the top-level module. Is this a limitation of the plugin or have I incorrectly configured something ?

Thanks.

Comment: I'd suggest moving to GWT 2.7 to run SDM. 2.6.1 is much buggier. SDM runs better and faster in GWT 2.7. It sounds like you may be running the app(module) in some iframe in the document possibly? If that's the case then it's not detectable (with bookmarklets, works fine in 2.7). I'd recommend, if you're using 2.7, that you use -war /path/to/war/ouput/dir. For instance using a external web server here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HfucNtGXLYY. If that doesn't help, how is your web server setup, are you using external or the built in jetty server?

Comment: Hi, I'm hosting my .WAR file on JBOSS and launching the code server using the Eclipse Jetty instance !

Answer (score 0):

If the SDM code server is running on the same ip as the web server then I suggest using the DevMode with the -war /path/to/war/output/dir/on/jboss so when the code server is launched it writes [module].nocache.js with sdm init in it to the war output directory. This means when it loads up it will compile and refresh compiles.

I prefer to use the code server launcher because it's easier to configure with external servers. The GWT Eclipse Plugin has a launcher for the code server, and instead of -war, it's call -launcherDir.

If the web server is on a different ip, either use proxy back to the code server is needed. This will route the 9867 request back to your local codeserver. Or hack and change the hostName in the [module].nocache.js. I'm working up a hack for this and will show how to run it at GWTCon. This wouldn't be needed if the server runtime were run from Eclipse because both the code server and web server are bound on the same ip.

Here is a video with a simple external web server on the same ip. The same effect can be had with any web server on the same ip. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HfucNtGXLYY

Comment: Seems to work okay for one of my modules, however I'm getting some RPC errors with the second module =(

Comment: Is there more than one project.nocache.js being embedded in the document?

Comment: I'm going to assume there is. In this case, only use SDM on one at a time, and compile the others and run them in web mode.

Comment: Hi, yes there is more than one. And I have tried with a single SDM but no luck, the only solution that kinda works is changing the <script> tag to point to the http://localhost:9876/example/project.no.cache file - however this results in having to debug the obfuscated .JS which isn't much help.

Comment: If only one module were to run in SDM and the others in web mode, and the project.nocache.js one of apps/modules has the the sdm initialization routine, and in that nocache.js file, the hosteName points to the code server address, I think it should work.

Comment: I'd be interested in a test case if you could build one.